# Do the Nagas ever try to conquer the 3 worlds?

Tags: naga, universe

It's well known that the Asuras, and sometimes the Rakshasas, try to conquer the 3 worlds.

My question is, do the Nagas, who live Patala, try to conquer the 3 worlds?

Comment: Bump............